# Compare two hashtable in powershell

Tags: powershell, compare, hashtable, powershell-2.0

Hello i'm beginner and I need to compare two hashtable and to have an other respawn.

For example :

```
[hashtable]$alpha =@{
"A1" = "computer";
"A2" = "folder";
"A3" = "plane";
"A4" = "flower";
"A5" = "dog";
}


[hashtable]$beta =@{
"computer" = "P1";
"plane" = "P2";
"garden" = "p3";
"flower" = "P4";
"dog" = "P5";
}
```

if i have Computer in `$alpha` and in `$beta` i need to write P1 for the user A1
if i have plane in `$alpha` and in `$beta` i need to write P2 for the user A3

Do i need to use for each ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: there is a compare-object function on the internet

Comment: I try compare-object by i didn't succeed to manipulate with `$alpha.keys`

Comment: What does your `compare-object` and _"manipulate with `$alpha.keys`"_ code look like? What output did you get (if any) and how does that differ from what you were expecting?

Comment: *if i have plane in $alpha and in $beta i need to write P2 for the user A2* Can you explain this? Why P2 for A2? `plane` in P2 and A3.

Comment: I try this : 
`foreach ($profil in $alpha)
{if ($profil.values -contains $beta.keys){
$ok = $beta.values
$ok}
else {
write-host "ko"}}`

Comment: i also try the method `Compare-Object` with `Compare-Object -referenceObject $alpha -DifferenceObject $beta` but i have this result _InputObject : System.collections.DictionaryEntry SideIndicator :_

Comment: @PetSerAl My apologize, y're right. I corrected my mistake

Comment: @PetSerAl Nice one, make it an answer. Derived `$alpha.GetEnumerator() | %{[PSCustomObject]@{aKey=$_.Key;aValue=$_.Value;bValue=$beta[$_.Value]}}`

Comment: Thanks @PetSerAl and LotPings it's work ! But can you explain to me in order to understand what i'm doing ..

Answer (score 9):

The solution has been already provided by [@PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) and [@LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) and is one of the following

```
$alpha.GetEnumerator() | select Key, @{ n='Value'; e={$beta[$_.Value]} }
$alpha.GetEnumerator() | %{[PSCustomObject]@{aKey=$_.Key;aValue=$_.Value;bValue=$beta[$_.Value]}}
```

Let me explain what exactly happens there.

First of all, as you use hashtables you cannot manipulate them directly using cmdlets like `Select-Object`. In order to do this you need to use `GetEnumerator()` method on it. Now you can pipe it to `Select-Object`.

To use the values from another hashtable you have to use calculated property instead of standard one. The syntax of it is:

```
@{ n='name'; e={ expression to be executed }
```

Let's dig into this expression `$beta[$_.Value]` a bit more. `$_` represents the object sent to pipeline so `$_.Value` is its value (as you know hashtables have key names and values). To better understand check this expression and its result

```
PS C:\> $alpha.GetEnumerator() | select -Last 1

Name                           Value
----                           -----
A5                             dog
```

For this entry `$_.Value` is `dog` so `$beta[$_.Value]` is evaluated to `$beta["dog"]` and its value is:

```
PS C:\> $beta["dog"]
P5
```

---

Additional resources:

1. [Microcode: PowerShell Scripting Tricks: The Joy of using Hashtables
   with Windows
   PowerShell](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mediaandmicrocode/2008/11/27/microcode-powershell-scripting-tricks-the-joy-of-using-hashtables-with-windows-powershell/)
2. [Add a calculated property with Select-Object in PowerShell](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/)
3. [Example of the same but with multiple values to be replaced (my answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51540315/9902555)