# Join two hashtables to make one

Tags: powershell, compare, hashtable

I have two hash tables and I need to compare them. Let me explain my problem :

```
[hashtable]$User = @{
"Jack" = "AdminLA, AdminUSA";
"John" = "AdminAustralia";
"Sarah" = "AdminIceland";
"Arnold" = "AdminUSA";
"Maurice" = "AdminAustralia, AdminCanada";
}


[hashtable]$Profil = @{
"AdminLA" = "P1";
"AdminIceland" = "P2";
"AdminUSA" = "P3";
"AdminCanada" = "P4";
"AdminAustralia" = "P5" ;
"AdminCroatia" = "P6";
}
```

I want to have this kind of result :

```
Key         Value
---         -----
Jack        P1, P3
John        P5
Sarah       P2
Arnold      P3
Maurice       P5, P4
```

Actually, I have only one value (I haven't succeeded to have multiple values. For example Jack must have P1 and P3 and I have only P1).

How can I fix it?

I have already tried:

```
$User.GetEnumerator() | select Key, @{n='Value'; e={$Profil[$_.Value]}}
```

and

```
$User.GetEnumerator() | %{[PSCustomObject]@{aKey=$_.Key;bValue=$Profil[$_.Value]}}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Ignoring comments and not acknowledging @robdy's helpful answers won't make you friends. You should take the [tour] and not ask quite [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51825301/compare-similar-values-from-hashtable-with-loop-in-powershell/51828056#51828056) again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this expression

```
$User.GetEnumerator() | Select-Object Key, @{name='Value'; expression={($_.Value -split ", " | Foreach-Object {$Profil[$_]}) -join ", "}}
```

This basically creates an array of input values, get the values from `$Profil` for each element and then creates a string from these values.

Comment: Sorry @Robdy ! I forget to answer you ! Yes, i use your expression in my script ! It's work great ! Thanks for all