# Compare similar values from hashtable with loop in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, compare, hashtable

I have 2 hash tables :

```
[hashtable]$Localisation = @{
"Macdo" = "OU=France,OU=Paris";
"BurgerKing" = "OU=USA,OU=LA";
"Quick" = "OU=Japan,OU=Tokyo";
}

[hashtable]$Profil = @{
"Big Mac" = "Macdo";
"Whooper" = "BurgerKing";
"Burger" = "Quick, BurgerKing, Macdo";
"Fries" = "BurgerKing, Macdo";
"Coke" = "Quick, Macdo";
"HappyMeal" = "Macdo";
}
```

I need to get this kind of result:

```
"Big Mac" = "OU=France,OU=Paris"
"Whooper" = "OU=USA,OU=LA";
"Burger" = "OU=Japan,OU=Tokyo, OU=USA,OU=LA, OU=France,OU=Paris"
"Fries" = "OU=USA,OU=LA, OU=France,OU=Paris";
"Coke" = "OU=Japan,OU=Tokyo, OU=France,OU=Paris";
"HappyMeal" = "OU=France,OU=Paris";
```

or

```
Big Mac      =  OU=France,OU=Paris
Whooper      =  OU=USA,OU=LA
Burger       =  OU=Japan,OU=Tokyo, 
                OU=USA,OU=LA, 
                OU=France,OU=Paris
Fries        =  OU=USA,OU=LA,
                OU=France,OU=Paris
Coke         =  OU=Japan,OU=Tokyo, 
                OU=France,OU=Paris
HappyMeal    =  OU=France,OU=Paris
```

I tried :

```
$tempLoca = @()

foreach ($value in $Profil.values) {
    if($Localisation.Contains($value)) {
        $tempLoca = $Localisation.Contains($value),$Profil.key
    }
}
```

But I get :

```
$tempLoca 
OU=France,OU=Paris
```

With my code I have only the last value. I don't know if I need to put my values in array or in hashtable (because they are multiple similar values).

Do you have an idea? Thanks

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51540315/9902555). It's similar case so you should be able to adapt the solution to your needs.

Comment: Actually it might be the same case as it's also your question...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[hashtable]$Localisation = @{
"Macdo" = "OU=France,OU=Paris";
"BurgerKing" = "OU=USA,OU=LA";
"Quick" = "OU=Japan,OU=Tokyo";
}

[hashtable]$Profil = @{
"Big Mac" = "Macdo";
"Whooper" = "BurgerKing";
"Burger" = "Quick, BurgerKing, Macdo";
"Fries" = "BurgerKing, Macdo";
"Coke" = "Quick, Macdo";
"HappyMeal" = "Macdo";
}


$tempLoca = @()
foreach ($key in $Profil.Keys) {
    $locals = ($Profil.$key -split ',') | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
    $result = @()
    foreach ($item in $locals) {
        if($Localisation.ContainsKey($item)) {
            $result += $Localisation.$item
        }
    } 
    $tempLoca += '"{0}" = "{1}"' -f $key, ($result -join '; ')
}

$temploca
```

It will output

```
"Big Mac" = "OU=France,OU=Paris"
"HappyMeal" = "OU=France,OU=Paris"
"Burger" = "OU=Japan,OU=Tokyo; OU=USA,OU=LA; OU=France,OU=Paris"
"Whooper" = "OU=USA,OU=LA"
"Fries" = "OU=USA,OU=LA; OU=France,OU=Paris"
"Coke" = "OU=Japan,OU=Tokyo; OU=France,OU=Paris"
```

**Note** that I combine the OU values from the $Localisation hash with a semicolon `;` to distinct them from the values themselves. If that is not what you want, just replace `($result -join '; ')` with `($result -join ', ')`

Comment: Thanks for the explication ! It's great !

Answer (score 3):

An IMO more PowerShell like way, building a PSCustomObject and grouping it:

```
$ProfileLocalisation = ForEach ($key in $Profil.Keys) {
    ForEach ($local in ($Profil.$key -split ',').Trim() ) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Profile = $key
            Localisation = $Localisation.$local
        }
    }
}
$ProfileLocalisation
```

Sample output:

```
Profile   Localisation
-------   ------------
Big Mac   OU=France,OU=Paris
HappyMeal OU=France,OU=Paris
Burger    OU=Japan,OU=Tokyo
Burger    OU=USA,OU=LA
Burger    OU=France,OU=Paris
Whooper   OU=USA,OU=LA
Fries     OU=USA,OU=LA
Fries     OU=France,OU=Paris
Coke      OU=Japan,OU=Tokyo
Coke      OU=France,OU=Paris
```

And grouped:

```
$ProfileLocalisation | Group-Object Profile | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Profile = $_.Name
        Localisations = ($_.Group.Localisation -join ';')
    }
}
```

---

```
Profile   Localisations
-------   -------------
Big Mac   OU=France,OU=Paris
HappyMeal OU=France,OU=Paris
Burger    OU=Japan,OU=Tokyo;OU=USA,OU=LA;OU=France,OU=Paris
Whooper   OU=USA,OU=LA
Fries     OU=USA,OU=LA;OU=France,OU=Paris
Coke      OU=Japan,OU=Tokyo;OU=France,OU=Paris
```

Comment: I can't use the first solution :  [System.String[] doesn't contain method "Trim". I use Powershell 2.0

And for the second (Grouped). Nothing happen