# Comparing 2 hashtables in powershell and output when different

Tags: powershell

I have got 2 hashtable definitions, did some research and saw this helpful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51514897/compare-two-hashtable-in-powershell/51553053)

This highlights the differences within the hashtables as per the code below.

```
[hashtable] $template = @{

    "ID" = "1"
    "Firstname" = "2"
    "Surname" = "3"
    "Grade Score" = "4"
    "City" = "5"
    "School Name" = "6"
}


[hashtable] $data = @{

    "1" = "ID"
    "2" = "Firstname"
    "3" = "Surname"
    "4" = "Grade"
    "5" = "City"
    "6" = "School"
    "7" = "Comments"
    "8" = "UpdateDate"
}
#$data.GetEnumerator() | sort -Property Key
#$data | Get-Member
#$data


$template_count = $template.Count
$data_count = $data.count

if ($template_count -ne $data_count)
{
    write-output "Template count of $template_count columns does not match data column count of $data_count "
}
$template.GetEnumerator() | select key,@{ n='Value'; e={$data[$_.value]}}
```

I can see the output as in

```
      ID          | ID
      ------------|-----------
      School Name |    School
      Surname     |  Surname
      Grade Score |    Grade
      City        |     City
      Firstname   | Firstname
```

In this case, the values School Name and School are different, so is Grade Score and Grade.
How can i highlight the differences ?

Comment: What do you mean by highlight the differences? Like 'Exact Match' = True / False or how?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? I'm not quite sure what you mean by "Highlight"

```
$expression={
    $re=[regex]$data[$_.Value]
    $match=$re.Match($_.Key).Value
    $_.Key -replace $match
}

$template.GetEnumerator() | select key,@{ n='Value'; e={$data[$_.value]}},@{n='Hightlight what does not Match?';e=$expression}


Key         Value     Hightlight what does not Match?
---         -----     -------------------------------
ID          ID                                       
School Name School     Name                          
Surname     Surname                                  
Grade Score Grade      Score                         
City        City                                     
Firstname   Firstname
```

Comment: Thanks for this, what I meant by highlight is say storing the columns that do not match in an array or custom object. Lastly on the data hash table, I would like to store the extra keys/values like comments and updateDate into the array or custom object.

Comment: The output of compare-object $($template.keys) $($data.Values) is what I would love, it shows differences in terms of Keys, whether name mismatch or new keys/values such as comments or updateDate. The issue with compare-objects is that I cannot easily process the output.